# PHP Line Indentation

Tags: php, coding-style

I'm curious to know, how many spaces of indentation do you prefer in PHP code?

```
function one()
{
 $one;
 function space()
 {
  $space;
 }
}

function two()
{
  $two;
  function spaces()
  {
    $spaces;
  }
}

function three()
{
   $three;
   function spaces()
   {
      $spaces;
   }
}

function four()
{
    $four;
    function spaces()
    {
        $spaces;
    }
}
```

Let's not make multiple answers for same indentation, but use the +1 for answers that fit your preferences.

Comment: make it community wiki - since there's no absolute answer.

Comment: What we need is a command line code formatter for php, so all php indents can be fixed automatically on checkin, and the team won't have to argue about it anymore.

Comment: I've never been one to accept things and not question...why? I always thought that many methods and coding styles came from a time when devices were smaller and servers were slower. When I'm coding I enjoy spacing it all out a bit more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One tab per level. The only correct way!

Comment: No, using tabs is NOT the python way. PEP-8 says to use (4) Spaces instead of Tabs: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

Comment: If one tab per level is "the only correct way", why do the PEAR coding guidelines say to use 4 Spaces instead of tabs? http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.indenting.php

Comment: And `tab` positions are always at every 8 space characters. Note that adding a `tab` in the middle of line is NOT same as blindly adding 8 spaces.

Comment: How did this get to be the accepted answer. This is absurd

Comment: Most coding software I use allow you to choose how many spaces is a tab. So if all code indentation used tabs, then in your preferred coding system (mine is Coda on a Mac) you can specify the number of spaces that represent the tab, and therefore show the indentation as you prefer, and no need to rely on the original developer. Therefore tabs should be preferred. Otherwise if you define spaces you are forcing your own personal preference on others. Personally I use tabs set to the equivalent of 4 spaces.

Comment: And set tab to every 4 spaces, consistent with the indentation, and then set auto convert tabs to spaces and you can hit the tab key and still conform to the standard, and avoid breakage in different environments.

Answer (score 11):

I use what's defined by the coding standards of the Framework I use for the project I'm working on :

- For instance, if I'm working on a [Drupal](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#indenting) based project, it's two spaces.
- If working on a project based on [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.indentation), it's four spaces.
- By default, if nothing else has been defined, I tend to use [PEAR coding standard](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php), which are well know and well accepted in the PHP community.

This way, everything in the project is consistent : it makes things easier for new people who start working on the project after it started.

*And, of course, this apply to other rules of formating too, like where to put the `{}`, for example.*

Comment: Use spaces becouse of the version control issues, and set up your editor to write 4 spaces instead of a tab.

Comment: @erenon: if your `tab` is not equal to going to next 8 character wide tab stop, stop pretending you're using `tab`s at all. You're just adding spaces with a shortcut key. Also, if your version control system gets broken for using proper `tab`s, it's time to replace that system with something that does work.

Answer (score 5):

After more years of software dev, I now follow the [PSR-2 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) of four spaces per level.

<s>2 spaces per level. It looks neat in Notepad.</s>

```
function testfunc($x){
  if($x & 1){
    return $x / 2;
  }
  return $x;
}
```

Comment: +1 I agree, PEAR has a standard of 4 spaces but, for me the readability is better with just 2 spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I use tabs, the various advanced text editors available for coders allow you to modify tab spaces at a later date.

I don't see why anyone would want to press space 4 times to produce an indent, it sounds like such a nuisance. I don't really care about what the proposed correct method is, I have something which suits me and is easier.

It's really not a big deal, my advice is to do what you feel. In the end, only you can decide.

Comment: Most decent editors will turn a <tab> into 4 (or 2, or 8, or whatever) spaces.

Comment: Not a single *decent* editori *will* turn `tab` into spaces. It *may* do it if configured to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I use four spaces like the [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/coding-standards.php) suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it as both way, whether it be spaces or tab. However personally I prefer 1 tab for my spacing as it's quick, easy and clean, not to mention it requires no thought as to how many times I've hit the space bar.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea for you to choose a Standard that [phpcodesniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/php_codesniffer) supports. That way you can run the phpcs tool on your code to scan for any deviations from whichever standard you choose.

Personally I favour the PEAR Coding Standards but you might prefer a different one.